# Could not invoke constructor for eg.add[0] in fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse

Here is my Fitnesse page:

```
!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h

!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path C:\Users\Jayasree
!path C:\Users\Jayasree\workspace\Selenium\bin\Sample
!|import|



!|add|
|num1|num2|sum()|
|10  |  2 |12  |
```

My fixture code:

```
package Sample;


import fit.ColumnFixture;


public class add extends ColumnFixture{

     public int a;
     public int b;
     public add(int a,int b)
     {
         this.a=a;
         this.b=b;
     }

        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setB(int b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
        public int sum() {
            return a+b;
        }


}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
variable defined: TEST_SYSTEM=slim 

classpath: C:\Users\Jayasree
classpath: C:\Users\Jayasree\workspace\Selenium\bin\Sample
import import: Bad table! Import tables must have at least two rows.



eg.add Could not invoke constructor for eg.add[0]
num1    num2    sum()
10 The instance decisionTable_1.setNum1. does not exist
2 The instance decisionTable_1.setNum2. does not exist
12 The instance decisionTable_1.setSum. does not exist
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The import table requires the names of the packages to import:

```
!|import|
|Sample|
```

`ColumnFixture` requries test system fit:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
```